# Avoid recreating the subject in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

Say I have the following test

```
describe "bob" do
  subject { 
    response = get "/expensive_lookup"
    JSON.parse(response.body) 
  }

  its(["transaction_id"]) { should == 1 }
  its(["order_id"]) { should == 33 }
end
```

Then for each `its() {}` the subject will be reevaluated, which in my case it is a very slow lookup.

I could bundle all my tests together in one like

```
describe "bob" do
  subject(res) { 
    response = get "/expensive_lookup"
    JSON.parse(response.body) 
  }

  it "returns the right stuff" do
    res["transaction_id"]).should == 1
    res["order_id"].should == 33
  end
end
```

But this makes it less obvious which line of the test has failed if there is a failure.

Is there a way I can stop the subject from being reevaluated for each `it` block?

Comment: Have you considered using [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr)?

Comment: Also, see here regarding the removal of `its` from RSpec. https://gist.github.com/myronmarston/4503509

Comment: Yeah might just end up using VCR, was hoping there would be a nicer way of just doing it in RSpec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put that in to a `before(:all)` block. I don't know if that syntax has changed in a new rspec version, but regardless, your test would become this:

```
before(:all) do
  response = get "/expensive_lookup"
  @res = JSON.parse(response.body)
end

it "returns the right transaction ID" do
  @res["transaction_id"].should == 1
end

# etc
```

The pro is that the code in the before-all block gets run just once for your spec. The con is that, as you can see, you can't take advantage of the subject; you need to write each more explicitly. Another gotcha is that any data saved to the test database is not part of the transaction and will not be rolled back.

Comment: You could add `subject { @res }` to make the implicit subject work.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible source of issues

#### Network request is slow/prone to fail

You should really mock all you network requests, slow or not.

The gem [`VCR`](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) is excellent. It makes it trivial to run your request once and persist the result for subsequent testing.

#### Building the immutable subject is slow

If you have multiple `it` blocks, the subject will be rebuild every time. Assuming you don't modify the subject, you can build it once.

You can use `before(:all)`:

```
before(:all) { @cache = very_long_computation.freeze }
subject { @cache }
```

*Note*: that I call `freeze` to avoid modifying it by mistake, but of course that's not a deep freeze so you still need to mind what you are doing. If you are mutating your subject, your tests are no longer independent and shouldn't share the subject.

Comment: I'm unable to get this to work. The `let` is executed for every `it`. The body of my `let` looks like this: `converter.convert_plantuml_to_svg(plantuml_content).to_s`. I don't quite understand how `.freeze` in the `subject` is going to tell RSpec to not execute the `let` before every test? Care to elaborate?

Comment: I changed my answer; using a class variable would work, but using `before(:all)` is better and more axiomatic.

Comment: Initially I got errors with this solution because I used a `subject` and `let` variable defined in a parent context inside the `before(:all)`, so I had to replace `subject` and `let` in the parent context with regular variable assignment. Not as idiomatic and clean, but it works. Thanks! The error message was:

"`let` and `subject` declarations are not intended to be called in a `before(:context)` hook, as they exist to define state that is reset between each example, while `before(:context)` exists to define state that is shared across examples in an example group."